# Page gets rendered before data is fetched

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, nuxtjs

I'm new to JS and I'm fetching some data with axios from my local API (Laravel)

Whenever I refresh the page with for example F5 or CTRL+R, the css is loaded before the content is there. That makes the page look ugly while loading data.

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: {},
        }
    },
    async fetch() {
        const data = await this.$axios.$get('/users?name=' + this.$route.params.name)
        this.user = data
        console.log(this.user.name)
    }
}
```

What can I do to prevent this?
Even if I add custom loaders the page will show for a second, then the loader will appear and will be there till its loaded. But why? And how do I make it look better?

EDIT: I know I need a loader, but apparently I'm implementing it wrong. As already said, there is already a loader but its only appearing like 1 seconds after refresh, before the loader appears there is always empty css/html showing with no content loaded.

Comment: You can use a loader, it won't show the content until your promise has been resolved completely

Comment: What you essentially want is to define the loading overlay at the top of your HTML page, then removing or hiding it at the end of the asynchronous task. Hope this helps - I would gladly share some snippets, but I am currently not at my computer.

Comment: I did try adding a isLoading bool into a try block, but that has the same affect as being written above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the v-if directive

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: {},
            isLoading: false
        }
    },
    async fetch() {
        this.isLoading = true
        const data = await this.$axios.$get('/users?name=' + this.$route.params.name)
        this.user = data
        this.isLoading = false
    }
}
```

...

```
<div>
    <div v-if="isLoading">Loader</div>
    <div v-else>Fetched content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to place it in these situations are called preloaders or you can also use skeletons from antd if you are using it. Here's a link for skeleton

https://ant.design/components/skeleton/#header

Also search for preloaders and you will find many in codepens or other links and implement those in your projects.

The concept behind preloaders is that they will be shown as the first thing in your page and when content is loaded you just hide or remove them completely from page.